# CMD+R wil not start Recovery HD - Fusion Drive

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, ssd

I have recently my Macbook Late 2009 with a SSD crucial 500Mo (Data doubler).
I made a Fusion Drive with no problems, then I re-installed el Capitan again with no issue (except I tried to re-install all my dat from my latest Time machine backup and it failed).
So the computer is working well, it boots up and shuts down at light speed as I expected :-)
Now my issue is that I am trying to recover my latest backup from Time Machine but I cannot get the HD Recovery at machine boot up.
I tried various keys combinations (CMD+R, R, Opt+R, CMD+OPT+R), nothing works.
Just to make sure I re-installed El Capitan just something went wrong. Same result.
then I started suspecting Fusion Drive.

Diskutil shows:
[image]

It seems that the system is installed on the SSD and the HD Recovery on the Hybrid disk. Could it be an explanation that HD recovery is not launched at boot-up?
Any idea how to fix this issue?

Regards.
@+  Gaël.

Comment: try booting up and pressing alt it should show all bootable partitions and drives also the recovery partition if you can't see it there then your recovery partition it self is broken